# Pass array/object from Javascript to Objective-C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

My question should be fairly simple to answer, but I can't seem to find anything in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html)

From my JS code I'm calling an Objective-C function with an array argument. E.g.:

```
ObjC.someFunction_([1,2,3]);
```

**Now in Objective-C, we have:**

```
- (void)someFunction:(WebScriptObject*)arr
{

}
```

As Apple suggests. (If it was a simple string then that's a whole different - and much simpler - story).

**The question is:** HOW do I convert this WebScriptObject into an `NSArray`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought of a workaround which works fine (although it's still a *workaround*) :

**In JS:**

```
ObjC.someFunction_(JSON.stringify([1,2,3]));
```

**In Objective-C:**

```
- (void)someFunction:(NSString*)arrStr
{
    NSArray* arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[arrStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
                                                   options:kNilOptions 
                                                     error:nil];
}
```

**In a schematic diagram:**

- Javascript -> Object to Json -> Objective-C -> Json to Object

---

*P.S. I'm sure there must be more elegant approaches (via the scarcely-documented `JavaScriptCore` perhaps?), but this one still does the trick! ;-)*